# WKWebView back and forward issue

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, wkwebview

I am using a IBAction for going back and forward

```
@IBAction func backButtonTapped(_ sender : UIBarButtonItem){
if webView.canGoBack{
            webView.goBack()
            webView.reload()
        }
}
```

Similar for forward button

In iOS 9,10,11 it works and after a while it stops
In iOS 12 doesn't work at all. It just refresh the same page.

If I remove the reload(), it works but then I can't reload the page.

Any suggestions ?